# Serve an i18n angular app on Firebase using functions

Tags: angular, firebase, express, internationalization, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to handle requests correctly to a localized angular app hosted on Firebase. The goal is to load the right app bundle depending on: 1) A cookie named `locale`. 2) The `accept-language` header. 3) Default to `en-us` when others are unavailable.

When localizing angular apps with i18n, angular-cli generates bundles (versions of your app) for each language/locale present in `angular.json`. Firebase serves your **bundles** as static content and it has serious security measurements disallowing path traversals.

I tried both setting *rewrites* and *redirects* in `firebase.json` but there is no facilities to intercept the `locale` cookie. Then, I used cloud functions to read the cookie, parse requests and return the right resource using `express`, `cookie-parser` and `express-locale`.

**1. Using hosting only**

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/en-us/**",
        "destination": "/en-us/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/es-co/**",
        "destination": "/es-co/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/zh-hans/**",
        "destination": "/zh-hans/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/en-us/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**2. Using cloud functions and express**

firebase.json

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "multilang"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

functions/index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const expressLocale = require('express-locale')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const _ = require('lodash')

const app = express()

const localeMap = {
  en: 'en_US',
  es: 'es_CO',
  zh: 'zh_TW',
  'en-US': 'en_US',
  'es-CO': 'es_CO',
  'zh-TW': 'zh_TW',
  'zh-Hans': 'zh_TW',
  en_US: 'en_US',
  es_CO: 'es_CO',
  zh_TW: 'zh_TW',
  zh_Hans: 'zh_TW'
}

const defaultLocale = 'en_US'

const baseMap = {
  en_US: 'en-us',
  es_CO: 'es-co',
  zh_TW: 'zh-hans'
}

app
  .use(cookieParser())
  .use(expressLocale({
    priority: ['cookie', 'accept-language', 'map', 'default'],
    default: defaultLocale,
    map: localeMap
  }))
  .use('**', (req, res, next) => {
    const locale = localeMap[req.locale.language]
    const sanitized = req.originalUrl.replace(/\.{2,}/g, '').replace(/\/{2,}/g, '/')
    const url = sanitized.split('/')
    const idx = url.length === 1 ? 0 : 1

    url[0] = _.values(baseMap).includes(url[idx]) ?
      url[idx] : (baseMap[locale] || baseMap[defaultLocale])

    if (url.length > 1 && url[0] === url[1]) {
      url.shift()
    }

    let file = path.resolve(`dist/${url.join('/')}`)

    if (!url[url.length - 1].match(/^[\w,\s-]+\.[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/) || !fs.existsSync(file)) {
      file = path.resolve(`dist/${url[0]}/index.html`)
    }

    res.sendFile(file)
  })

exports.multilang = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

The last settings work well for a local Firebase emulation resolving path to index.html or any other requested file (say it `ngsw-worker.js` for progressive apps support).

When deploying to Firebase it fails resolving and finding the hosted files (e.g. `index.html`), even if you change path to:

- `/${url[0]}/index.html`
- `../${url[0]}/index.html`
- `/public/${url[0]}/index.html`

Or rewriting `req.sendFile` to `req.redirect`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Carlos, did you manage to find a solution to your problem ?

Comment: Hi @JohanChouquet, yes, I finally found a more simple solution. Let me share it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same problem, here is a naive solution using firebase functions:

#### functions/index.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const expressLocale = require('express-locale')
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

const localeMap = {
  en: 'en_US',
  es: 'es_CO',
  zh: 'zh_CN',
  en_US: 'en_US',
  es_CO: 'es_CO',
  zh_Hans: 'zh_CN'
}

const prefixMap = {
  en_US: 'en-us',
  es_CO: 'es-co',
  zh_CN: 'zh-hans',
}

const defaultLocale = 'en_US'
const app = express()

app
  .use(cookieParser())
  .use(expressLocale({
    priority: ['cookie', 'accept-language', 'map', 'default'],
    default: defaultLocale,
    map: localeMap
  }))
  .use('*', (req, res, next) => {
    const locale = localeMap[req.locale.language]
    const prefix = prefixMap[locale] || prefixMap[defaultLocale]
    res.redirect(`/${prefix}${req.originalUrl}`)
  })

exports.multilang = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

#### firebase.json

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/your-app-name",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/en-us/**",
        "destination": "/en-us/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/es-co/**",
        "destination": "/es-co/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/zh-hans/**",
        "destination": "/zh-hans/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "multilang"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Carlos, thanks for sharing this. My only concern is the solution should only trigger the function 'multilang' for Users who go to 'mydomain.com', which should trigger the function which would redirect to the right locales which in the end would redirect to the index.html of each angular app. Do you confirm this is the case ? I wouldn't want the function to be triggered 'every time' a User launches any url from all your locales.

Comment: Another question: what's the use of the cookie parser in your function? You don't seem to do any treatment about cookies.

Comment: Good question @JohanChouquet. If the user fires any url explicitly on the browser, multilang triggers. If the user navigates through routerLinks, it doesn't. It would be a great enhancement finding a way to reduce those function calls.

Comment: On the other hand, expressLocale library sets a cookie with your default locale once triggered. That's where the cookieParser lib takes place.

Comment: Hi @JohanChouquet, do you think it's possible to improve this solution for function call optimization? have you run any additional experiment? Please let me know if you have some findings.